# How to prompt user to select a folder from gallery to save files. Instead of Saving files directly to the internal storage?

Tags: android

In the code below, I am saving data to the internal storage by using the `getExternalFilesDir()` method.  But now I want to prompt the user to open the gallery and select the folder where he wants to store the data.
Please note, I was passing the result of `getExternalFilesDir()` method to `FileOutputStream(f)`. Same I have to do now.
How can I do this?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
final File f = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("received"),
                            "wifip2pshared-");
    
                    File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
                    if (!dirs.exists())
                        dirs.mkdirs();
                    f.createNewFile();
    
                    InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
                    copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
                    serverSocket.close();
                    return f.getAbsolutePath();
```

I am using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT for this, this is code I have written till now. It is opening the gallery and selecting the file. But I do not how I will get the value of "f" to pass into FileOutputStream(f).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myfile");
        startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/11/09/scoped-storage-stories-trees.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tried using it. But I do not know, how I will get the value of "f" from it to pass into FileOutputStream(f). Please see the question as I have edited it and added the code in which I used ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT.

Comment: "But I do not know, how I will get the value of "f" from it to pass into FileOutputStream(f)" -- if you are creating content, **there is no file** and so there is no `FileOutputStream`. With `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, you get a `Uri` identifying where the user wants you to write that content. Use that with `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` onto which you can write your content. See https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am unable to understand how I will use this URI. Please help me by writing some code in the answer section for saving data to the place represented by URI using Outputstream. I will be very thankful.

Comment: [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v1.0/ContentEditor) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack)) demonstrates the use of `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.